# Function that returns next Friday from date

Tags: excel, vba

When planning projects we give a approximate duration in weeks. A project starts on the next Monday from today.

```
Public Function NextMonday() As Date

Dim D As Integer
Dim N As Date

D = Weekday(Now)
N = Now() + (9 - D)

NextMonday = N

End Function
```

With this code I can assign the right date to a cell (Next Monday). Now i need to get the next Friday 12 weeks from that date. (84 Days)

For this i used the previous code and adjusted it a little.

```
Public Function NextFriday(AproxDate As Date) As Date

Dim E As Integer
Dim M As Date

E = Weekday(Now)
M = AproxDate + (14 - E)

NextFriday = M

End Function
```

Now for the main module the code looks like;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
Dim StartDate As Range
Dim AproxDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Range

Set wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook
Set wsCurrent = wbCurrent.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set StartDate = wsCurrent.Range("C15")
Set EndDate = wsCurrent.Range("C16")

Call NextMonday
StartDate.Value = NextMonday
'Setting Monday 12 weeks from StartDate
AproxDate = NextMonday + 84

Call NextFriday(AproxDate)
EndDate.Value = NextFriday

End Sub
```

The NextMonday part works fine, but when running the NextFriday i get an "Argument Not Optional" When trying to set the EndDate.Value = NextFriday.

I cant seem to find the problem with this code. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't call the function  `NextFriday` without including the parameter is requries `(AproxDate As Date)`.

Comment: Just add 88 days to the Monday date (84 for the 12 weeks and 4 for the datediff between Friday and Monday)

Comment: @ashleedawg This did the trick. Thanks for pointing that out. Code work perfectly fine now!

Comment: You usually don't use `Call` for `Function` (well, you usually don't use `Call` at all, since it's not required) Here your two `Call ...` lines are of no use at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you get a value from a function:

```
Call NextFriday(AproxDate)
EndDate.Value = NextFriday
```

If you want the value that function `NextFriday` returns based on `(AproxDate)` and you want that value in cell `EndDate` then (instead of both lines above) you would use:

```
EndDate.Value = NextFriday(AproxDate)
```

You only use `Call` with a function if you do **not** want a value to be returned from it.

---

## Simplified Procedures:

Your procedure are needlessly overcomplicated.

Believe it or not, **this is *exactly* the same as your procedures**:

```
Public Function NextMonday() As Date
    NextMonday = Now() + (9 - Weekday(Now))
End Function

Public Function NextFriday(AproxDate As Date) As Date
    NextFriday = AproxDate + (14 - Weekday(Now))
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    .Range("C15")= NextMonday
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C16")= NextFriday(NextMonday + 84)
End Sub
```

---

## Simplified *even further*:

Going a step further, **this is 1 sub is *exactly* the same as the 3 procedures above**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("C15") = Now() + (9 - Weekday(Now))
        .Range("C16") = (.Range("C15") + 84) + (14 - Weekday(Now))
    End With
End Sub
```

---

One more thing to note, function `Now` returns the current date+time.  Id it's only the date you're interested in, use function `Date`.

Comment: The simplified even further code works really well. Only thing is that now the (13 - Weekday(Now)) (It says 14 in my code, but should be 13) doesn't seem to work correctly. When using a variable for the date in .Range("C16") and using that in the Weekday("Variable") it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 mistakes in your Next Friday function.

1) from Monday to Friday in Weekdays is +4 and not +5 (so you get Next Monday = +9 and next Friday = +(9+4) )

2) You took the now() instead of aproxdate in the next friday code

Your code for next friday should be:

```
Public Function NextFriday(AproxDate As Date) As Date

Dim E As Integer
Dim M As Date

E = Weekday(AproxDate)
M = AproxDate + (13 - E)

NextFriday = M

End Function
```

Then you can call the function as in the other answer

Comment: You were right about these things thanks for pointing out those mistakes. Though i still get the "Argument Not Optional" when running.

Comment: Yes you can refers to Ashleedawg for the calling part :)

Comment: @Pierre44  - Nice answer, I wasn't even considering the math...  Does everyone get a "high" by shrinking code, or is that just me?  ...i just shrunk that baby by 85%!  :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg and I only considered the math and not the rest of the question :-D. what do you mean by a "high"?

Comment: @Pierre44 - As in, I'm such a geek, this kind of stuff is my primary source of entertainment.  lol

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (5+7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
document.write(d);
```

This is a Javascript code which will result you next friday, the only condition where it fails if it is a friday.

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  If you look just below the question you'll see it's tagged with ([tag:excel-vba]), so JavaScript won't help here.  Good on you for jumping on it anyway!  (Click this ([tag:javascript]) to find some js questions to answer!)